# How to use "actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE" app action from google assistant?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

How would you implement actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE action from Google Assistant?

The documentation is missing examples.

Comment: I also tried and I could not understand how to do it either. Missing examples and doc.

Comment: I can't answer since @yvette-colomb closed the question since it was not clear before edited.

OPEN_APP_FEATURE does not belong to a specific vertical you can use it to open features of your app. The missing part in the docs is the parameter (it will be fix).

<action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">

    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://example.com/open{?featureName}">

        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="feature"
            urlParameter="featureName" />

    </fulfillment>

</action>